# how to sort children in acestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ancestry

I am using the ancestry gem with a model called MenuHeader

```
class MenuHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
```

And for example this data model

```
id name          ancestry position
1  MenuHeader#1  NULL     1 
2  MenuHeader#2  1        1 
3  MenuHeader#3  1/2      2 
4  MenuHeader#4  1/2      1
```

With this representation:

```
1. MenuHeader#1
  2. MenuHeader#2   
      4. MenuHeader#4 position 1
      3. MenuHeader#3 poition 2
```

Looking at the README at https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry ; it's not clear how I would achieve this or whether this is possible? I tried putting a scope on it but that didn't seem to work. It seems as if

```
<% menu_header.children.is_not_deleted.each do |menu_header|  %>
  <%= render 'menus/ancestry/menu_header_form', menu_header: menu_header %>
<% end %>
```

would like to be:

```
<% menu_header.sorted_children.is_not_deleted.each do |menu_header|  %>
  <%= render 'menus/ancestry/menu_header_form', menu_header: menu_header %>
<% end %>
```

but not sure how to do do this. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Edit #1 
I have seen this:

```
Note that since materialised path trees don’t support ordering within a rank, the order of siblings depends on their order in the original array.
```

in the discussion of sorting but it seems like I should be able to pass a lambda to how this should be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use acts_as_list coupled with ancestry to sort my node

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Comment: thx, forgot I asked this. I tried using ancestry but the fact that you have to use integers is a deal-breaker. ending up writing my own to handle floats. Maybe should make a PR for it.